# yii2 seperate comma data in the gridview for each entry of the relation

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have 3 tables and i have made relation to What table by using Field table. i want to show name row from What table in Gridview.but it shows me row of data seperated by comma. i want each data in different column. like sql query result with repeated field. 
this is my tbon.php model:

```
public function getWhat()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(What::className(), ['idw' => 'idw'])
            ->viaTable('Field', ['id' => 'id']);
    }
public function getField()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Field::className(), ['id' => 'id']);
    }
```

and in TbonSearch.php i have added these codes:

```
public $what;
public $field;
```

and

```
[['field','what'],'safe']
```

and in search method, i have added:

```
$query = Tbon::find()
           ->joinWith(['field'])
           ->joinWith(['what']);
```

and for sorting:

```
$dataProvider->sort->attributes['what'] = [
            'asc' => ['what.name' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['what.name' => SORT_DESC],

        ];
```

and add search filter:

```
->andFilterWhere(['like', 'what.name', $this->what]);
```

in index i have added this code and here is the problem, i think:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],           
            'id',
            [
                'label'=>'Name',
                'attribute' => 'what',
                'value' => function ($data) {
                    $str = '';
                    foreach($data->what as $name) {
                        $str .= $name->name.',';
                    }
                    return $str;
                },
            ],
```

data is like this: a,b,c,d for field of name! but i want ID and a then in next row ID and b and etc.
 
any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know your code and I dont get the meaning, but I can answer in general.

A GridView is used to view Data in a Grid. A row in a GridView represents a dataset and presenting data in the form of a table.

```
foreach($data->what as $name) {
                    $str .= $name->name.',';
                }
```

I assume you want to display the **Name** attribute from the relation **what**. You can simply achieve this with the **[tablename.columnname](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html#$columns-detail)** syntax.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],           
        'id',
        [
            'label'=>'Name',
            'attribute' => 'what.name',
        ],
```

If you want to display the ID column additionally:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],           
        'id',
        [
            'label'=>'Name',
            'attribute' => 'what',
            'value' => function ($data) {
                $str = '';
                foreach($data->what as $name) {
                    $str .= ' ';
                    $str .= $name->id.'';
                    $str .= $name->name.',';
                }
                return $str;
            },
        ],
```

To be more precise (in Terms of your Problem). We have a datamodel with a junction table like the following simple book database.

[image: datamodel of a simple book database]

Example:

If you want to display the names of the authors on the standard CRUD generated index Gridview, you can do something like this:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'book_name',
        [
            'label'=>'Author(s)',
            'value' => function ($dataProvider) {
                $str = '';
                foreach($dataProvider->authors as $name) {
                    $str .= ' ';
                    $str .= $name->id.' ';
                    $str .= $name->author_name.',';
                }
                return $str;
            },
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

with the result:

[image: index books]

In addition, you can edit the Detail View to display such an information in an extra Gridview. The result can look like this.

[image: detail view of a book]

To achieve this you have to:

1. add a data provider to your controller and pass the provider to the view
2. add a gridview widget in your view and connect the data provider
3. add a method to your model which crawls the data

view.php aka the view

```
use yii\grid\GridView;

// other code

<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
        'id',
        [
            'attribute' => 'author.author_name',
            'header' => 'Author(s)',
        ],
    ],

]); ?>
```

BookController.php aka the controller

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $dataProvider = Book::getAllAuthors($id);
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Book.php aka the model

```
use \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;

// other code

public static function getAllAuthors($id) {

    $query = BookAuthor::find()->where(['book_id' => $id]);
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    return $dataProvider;

}
```

Comment: yes i want to do that! but i can not. because my relation is HasMany and it returns array so i can not use the way that you have mentioned.when i do as  that it shows [not set]. and one more thing... my table is tbwhats and i am using what for relation as you can see it in getWhat function.

Comment: to provide a correct answer: can you upload a database schema?

Comment: Thanks R13e for your in depth answer. My goal is exactly at the result of Books you have shown, in the Authors part. there you can see you have shown all writers of the book just in one field... 1 Douglas, 3 Garry, 2 Jane ... and separate them by ",". i want make 3 redundant rows and in each Douglas, other Garry and the third be Jane. exactly as shown in extra Gridview, but plus the ID and the book name repeat.  Thank you again.

Comment: In my humble opinion, it still makes no sense. Which data contains your dataProvider? 3 rows with the same ID, or returns the dataProvider exactly one row with {ID, a, b, c, d}? What would you achieve?

Comment: you're opinion is right, but in my case really necessary to show data like as i said. your help is appreciated.

Comment: Please dont turn this into a chat. Update your first post with a matrix, which shows the data that you expect and which data contains your DataProvider.